# Spacemacs how to navigate help (paging)?

Tags: spacemacs

I am trying to view the list of keybindings. I do this:

`SPC h k`

I see this: `C-h paging/help`

[image]

How do I navigate to see the next page?

Thanks!

(I'm using spacemacs develop branch with Colemak keybindings if this messes anything up...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That message is telling you that to get to the paging commands or to get to help you need to press `C-h`. After you press `C-h`, the paging commands will be active, and you can press `n` to get to the next page. I don't think Colemak should interfere, but I don't know for certain.

Comment: Thanks Sam, I was having issues with actually inputing `C-h`, I was able to diagnose via `SPC h d k`, I belive my terminal software was not allowing me to press `C-h` (Ctrl-h) 

If anyone else has this issue, you can read more about it here: 

https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/10509#issuecomment-376314380

https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/32693/how-do-i-page-when-esc-1-of-n-c-h-paging-help-shows-in-the-emacs-status

Comment: Oh, that's very interesting! Thanks for including the link to your github issue! For anyone from the future reading, `SPC h d k` calls the function `describe-key`